# Want to pass dynamic File path from main web application to a separate DLL. That DLL is separately done using NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

This is the code I am using to pass the file path and giving the file path in NLOG.config file in DLL (class library) from other web application to generate the logs file . But I am unable to do this.

```
string filePath = path;
var target = (FileTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("logFile");
target.FileName = "" + filePath + "/current.log";
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
```

Comment: What's not working? Looks valid to me.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there is only one global NLog.config for the entire application.

Instead of modifying the individual targets in the active NLog-config, then I think it is easier to modify the NLog global variables.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer

You could do it like this:

```
<target type="file" filename="${gdc:item=MyAppPath}current.log" />
```

And then at startup execute this command to modify the GDC:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("MyAppPath", filePath + "/");
```